# Number of compositions of a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with at least two parts.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

So I have to show  that the number of partitions of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is $2^{n-1} -1 $. ( the order is important ).

So here is my attempt. Please be strict. If you find any mistake or something that iritates you, let me know:

We rewrite $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$n = 1 + \cdots + 1 $ .(  we sum $1$ $n$-times).
We want to find the number of compositions with at least two parts, so we consider "$+$". For each "$+$"  between the summands we have to decide if the summands are a "new" summand or not. We get $2^{n-1}$ decisions. But we don't count the solution $n = n$ , so we have $2^{n-1} -1$.

What do you say? Remark: Please focus on my work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not what I call partitions.

Comment: ok. any other suggestions?

Comment: Partitions where order matters are usually called "compositions".  In addition $n$ would usually be considered a composition of itself, so you're looking to count compositions of $n$ with at least two parts.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)
confirms both your answer and your argument.